# Limits under multiple \sum

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I would like to place a lower limit under two consecutive `\sum`s, somewhere in between. So I have `\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}` and would like to place `j>k` in the lower limit between the two sums. I believe the multiple integral operator has this kind of functionality.

Comment: Wouldn't `\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{j}` do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Something like:

`\mathop{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}}_{j>k}`

maybe?

Looks like this:

[image]

Or if you want it on the same line as j=1 and k=1, then maybe:

`\mathop{\sum^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}}_{j=1\  j>k\ k=1}`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is an equivalent alternative.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \underset{j>k}{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}}
  \]
\end{document}
```