# Equation with two sums but just one min and max

Tags: equations, amsmath

I started with equations now and I got a problem with two sums in a row which should have the same symbol for minimum and the same symbol for maximum obove / under the sum symbols. The min and max should be in the middle of both sum symbols.

This is what I got right now:

```
\underbrace{\sum\sum^{N_{el}}_{I=1} \frac{Z_I}{r_{iI}}}_{\hat{V_{ee}}}
```

The code line is compiled ih the environment for equations. What I need is, is that the N_{el}is in the middle of both symbols and I=1 under both symbols. I used the amsmah package. But I could not find a way to work out the problem.

Comment: [math mode - Limits under multiple \sum - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25070/limits-under-multiple-sum)

Comment: [math mode - Text across several summation symbols - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219441/text-across-several-summation-symbols/219446#219446) ; [macros - Custom Math Symbol - Two Sigma Sums - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367662/custom-math-symbol-two-sigma-sums) ; [math mode - How to place the subscript under two summation signs in a fraction? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225315/how-to-place-the-subscript-under-two-summation-signs-in-a-fraction/225317#225317)

Answer (score 5):

You make `\sum\sum` into a single mathop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\underbrace{\mathop{\sum\sum}^{N_{el}}_{I=1} \frac{Z_I}{r_{iI}}}_{\hat{V_{ee}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

But the final result is far from being pretty. And *why* two summation signs? Also, please, fix the `\hat{V_{ee}}` horrible thing. It should likely be `\hat{V}_{ee}`.

[image]