# How to do this double sum with a subscript in the middle?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, statistics

This is

[image]

How to do this double sum with a subscript in the middle?

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate: `\mathop{\sum\sum}_{i<j}` See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649824/4427

Answer (score 2):

Not finding a specific duplicate, I'll repeat the code used in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649824/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{cov}

\begin{document}

\[
2\mathop{\sum\sum}_{i<j} a_{i}a_{j}\cdot \cov(X_{i}X_{j})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To be honest, I'd use a single summation sign.

Comment: Excellent!. Thank you.